# best way to tell swaggerui where the host is

Tags: swagger-ui

When I build my swagger.json file I do not know which host to use. However I can work it out when my page that hosts swaggerui loads (in fact I might want to offer the user a choice). I hoped to see an options.host on the config for the swaggerUI object - I dont see one. Is there an existing way of doing this that I cant find or do I simply have to hack my way through the code and add this capability (pointers to the best place to do it would be welcome)

Comment: is this helpful? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/ZGYTzP0DCNM
Appears it may not be possible to set dynamically currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

two ways

One modify swagger.js so that it accepts host option. swagger-UI passes options to swagger-js so that works. I submitted a pull to swagger-js with this fix

Second choice is that swagger-UI accepts a 'spec' parameter. This means that the hosting page can load the swagger.json file, JSON.parse it , set 'host' in it and then pass to swaggerUi constructor. This is harder for the caller but doesn't require code changes to swagger

Comment: In case people want to monitor the status of @pm100 pull request it's located at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/pull/510#issuecomment-121776076

Comment: do you have an example of using the 'spec' parameter?

Answer (score 8):

Swagger has a built-in json definition for host config, or can accept multiple inputs.

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "Why API",
        "description": "Don't make that mistake again",
        "version": "0.0.1"
    },

    "host": "127.0.0.1:3000",
    "schemes": [
        "https"
    ]
}
```

Or

```
"host": "test.mydomain.com:3000",
"schemes": [
    "https"
],
```

Or you can have a dynamic host by defining a var and calling a hostname or machine name or other environment variables.

## dynamic example

```
if (typeof this.host === 'undefined' || this.host === '') {
  this.host = location.host;
}
if (location.port) {
  this.host = this.host + ':' + location.port;
}
```

Comment: the first part doesnt match what I need. I dont know the host at the time I write swagger.json. Second part basically says change the code in swagger-js/lib/client.js. Without saying what the mod is - in fact i worked this out and submitted a pull to that file

Comment: Suggest that this answer should be removed since it does not address what the OP is actually asking, as he indicates above.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I do, since the loaded in document is just a JSON object:

```
var swaggerDoc = require('./api/swagger.json');
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  swaggerDoc.host="localhost:" + process.env.PORT
}

// Initialize the Swagger middleware
swaggerTools.initializeMiddleware(swaggerDoc, function (middleware) {
  // Other initialization
}
```

This way you don't pollute your API specification with development environment configuration.

Answer (score 5):

If you are hosting it on same app server, just remove the host key from the json and provide relative path in key "basePath". as -
"basePath": "/rest/createcampaign".

Answer (score 4):

In recent versions of Swagger UI it's possible to do this, for example in onComplete:

`window.swaggerUi.api.setHost("your.host:4242");`

Comment: Running this in my debug console was a nice quick and dirty solution for me. thanks!

Comment: so helpful for temporary fix

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways which you can follow:

1. Load the index.html and replace the https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json with the url where your `swagger.json` is hosting.
   you can expose the local `swagger.json` on the same server.
   When you follow this approach make sure you include static files in the end of above steps.
   If you don't want to expose `swagger.json` as an API, copy the `sawgger.json` in the dist folder of swagger. The index.html and swagger.json must be in same repository for this.  It is inside the `index.html` of dist folder of swagger-ui-dist.

```
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
          spec: location.host,
          url: "swagger.json",
          dom_id: "#swagger-ui",
          deepLinking: true,
          presets: [SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis, SwaggerUIStandalonePreset],
          plugins: [SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl],
          layout: "StandaloneLayout"
        });
        // End Swagger UI call region

        window.ui = ui;
      };
```

2. Second way, host parameter in the `swagger.yaml/swagger.json` either make it empty
   `"host":""`
   or omit host parameter.
   Swagger take the server's host as host where the swagger ui is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did this using the Java client:

```
DefaultApi api = new DefaultApi();
api.getApiClient().setBasePath("http://localhost:8080");
//call the API
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use OpenApi 3.0

> Variables can have arbitrary values, or may be restricted to an enum. In any case, a default value is required, which will be used if the client does not supply a value.

[swagger doc](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/)

In the swagger-ui there will be the default value but the field is an input field so it is possible to customize it at runtime.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Swagger UI express itself is giving the following snippet it's getting the current host and publish dynamic with host

```
app.use('/api-docs', function(req, res, next){
    swaggerDocument.host = req.get('host');
    req.swaggerDoc = swaggerDocument;
    next();
}, swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version > 3, the following code will work

```
  "servers": [{ "url": "https://api.example.com" }],
```