# generating swagger YAML from template?

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am trying to find a solution where I have something like a YAML template with variables, and a configuration file with variable definitions. I run this tool on the YAML template and it will generate a YAML file for each configuration file.

I am honestly most likely not searching using the right keywords online. But if any one has any recommendations or knows of such a tool to accomplish this, it would be much appreciated :).

Comment: Normally your swagger is auto-generated using code annotations which does this. Can you explain more about your use case?

Comment: @Charlie In the yaml file lets say I have a hostname that needs to change according to the current state of the project. Does that fit the description of using code annotations?

Comment: If you aren't pointing say Swagger UI to auto-generated code then you could do what's suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927957/best-way-to-tell-swaggerui-where-the-host-is Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with any templating library you want, provided your substitutions are fairly simple. For example, you could use the [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) library from Ruby's standard library:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'erb'
require 'yaml'

def render(template, data)
  ERB.new(template).result(binding)
end

template = ARGF.file.read
ARGF.skip

until ARGF.closed?
  puts "[#{ARGF.filename}]"
  data = ARGF.file.read
  ARGF.skip
  puts render(template, YAML.load(data))
  puts
end
```

### Usage

#### `config-1.yml`:

```
---
first_name: Yukihiro
last_name: Matsumoto
```

#### `config-2.yml`:

```
---
first_name: Alan
last_name: Kay
```

#### `template.yml.erb`:

```
person:
  first_name: <%= data["first_name"] %>
  last_name: <%= data["last_name"] %>
  email: <%= data["first_name"].downcase %>.<%= data["last_name"].downcase %>@example.com
```

#### Command line

```
$ ./template_merge.rb template.yml.erb config-1.yml config-2.yml
[config-1.rb]
person:
  first_name: Yukihiro
  last_name: Matsumoto
  email: yukihiro.matsumoto@example.com

[config-2.rb]
person:
  first_name: Alan
  last_name: Kay
  email: alan.kay@example.com
```

### Edit

Re: Your question about data nested under a top-level mapping key:

```
---
Person:
  first_name: Yukihiro
  last_name: Matsumoto
```

When you do `YAML.load(data)` with the above data, instead of the resulting Hash looking like this:

```
{ "first_name" => "Yukihiro",
  "last_name" => "Matsumoto" }
```

...it will look like this:

```
{ "Person" => {
    "first_name" => "Yukihiro",
    "last_name"  => "Matsumoto"
  }
}
```

So to get at `first_name` and `last_name` you just need to do `object["Person"]`:

```
until ARGF.closed?
  puts "[#{ARGF.filename}]"
  data = YAML.load(ARGF.file.read)
  ARGF.skip
  puts render(template, data["Person"])
  puts
end
```

Comment: Interesting Solution! I am going to give it a try and see if it does what I need it to. :)

Comment: Your example doesn't work, I have been trying to piece it together I keep getting the following error:                                                                          (erb):2:in `render': undefined local variable or method `first_name' for main:Object (NameError)
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/erb.rb:849:in `eval'
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/erb.rb:849:in `result'
 from ./yamGen.rb:6:in `render'
 from ./yamGen.rb:21:in `<main>'

Comment: Sorry, I should have had `data["first_name"]` instead of `first_name`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you Jordan! quick question, how would I access data if it was iterative. EG. if config file was " people: first_name: yukihiro last_name:matsumoto "

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "iterative." Can you edit your question to include an example of the YAML?

Comment: I edited the config-1.yml file in your example. Under a situation where the config file looks like that. How would I go about using ERB to insert first_name and last_name.

Comment: Also what if one of my variable contains single quotes? how do I escape this so it shows up on the final yaml file generated?

Comment: I've updated my answer with information on accessing keys in a hash. As for escaping quotes, you generally do not need to escape quotes (or most other characters) in YAML unless they appear at the very beginning of a string. However, that's beyond the scope of this question. If you're experiencing a specific problem I recommend posting a new question with the YAML and data you have.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance!